# Generate all multiplicative (product) combinations of columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations, python-itertools

I would like to generate all 2-way (and possibly 3-way) "multiplicative" combinations (i.e., column1 x column2, column2 x column3, column1 x column3, column1 x column 2 x column3, etc) of a pandas dataframe with about 100 columns (and 500K rows). I plan to evaluate these combinations for identifying high performing 'feature interactions' in a predictive model.

Thus far, my attempts (at either repurposing existing stackoverflow suggestions or other online materials) to generate the combinations have not been successful. Here is my minimal example with a very simple dataframe and the code I am using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':[10,20], 'height':[5, 6], 'weight':[100,150]})

sample_list = df.columns.to_list()
output = list(combinations(sample_list, 2))

pd.DataFrame(df[x].prod(axis = 1) for x in output)
```

My above code yields a "key error: ('age', 'height').  The final output should contain all 2-way (and potentially 3-way) 'multiplicative' combinations only (i.e., not include the original columns).
[image]

Can somebody please guide me to the solution? Also, how would one modify the code to generate all 3-way combinations? Any suggestions to optimize for limited RAM (~30GB) are also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the values of your dataframe should be int.
Secondly, `prod` returns the product of values along a given axis. IIUC you want the product of two columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':[10,20], 'height':[5, 6], 'weight':[100,150]})

sample_list = df.columns.to_list()
output = list(combinations(sample_list, 2))

for x,y  in output:
    df[f'{x}*{y}']= df[x] * df[y]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   age  height  weight  age*height  age*weight  height*weight
0   10       5     100          50        1000            500
1   20       6     150         120        3000            900
```

###### Edit:

This solution can be generalized for products of any length, just replace your loop with:

```
from functools import reduce
for tup in output:
    df['*'.join(tup)]= reduce(lambda a,b: a*b, [df[i] for i in tup])
```

Comment: Beat me to the `reduce` approach! Consider the functional form of arithmetic operators such as `Data Frame.mul/div/add/sub` instead of `*|/|+|-`.

Comment: You're right! they allow to specify a `fill_value` which can be quite convenient...

Comment: Very elegant and readable! I modified your code slightly to only retain 2-way combns based on Parfait's approach below: ```output = list(combinations(sample_list, 2))

for x,y  in output:
    df[f'{x}*{y}']= df[x] * df[y]
    ndf2 = df.drop(sample_list, axis = 1)

ndf2``` I dont fully follow the generalized code (for products of any length) although it worked if one declares the output up front as done by Parfait as 'combns'. It seems easier to split the above code first to generate 2-way combinations and 3-way combinations separately (for me).

Comment: Instead of explicitly unpacking the values of the tuples in `output` you work with a tuple (`tup`) that can be of any length. `'*'.join(tup)` builds the column name out of the tuple elements while `[df[i] for i in tup]` is a list containing all df-columns to be multiplied (multiplication occurs via `reduce`).

Comment: That way it doesn't matter whether `output = list(combinations(sample_list, 2))` or  `output = list(combinations(sample_list, 3))` or `output = list(combinations(sample_list, 2)) + list(combinations(sample_list, 3))`

Comment: If one doesnt explicitly declare "output" for the generalized code, then it only generates 3-way combos (or the combination of all columns in df). However, your generalized solution is very useful when output is explicitly declared upfront as done here            ```
columns_list = df.columns.to_list()
output = (list(combinations(columns_list, 2)) + list(combinations(columns_list, 3)))
   
for tup in output:
    df['*'.join(tup)]= reduce(lambda a,b: a*b, [df[i] for i in tup])
    ndf = df.drop(columns_list, axis = 1)    
ndf```  Thank you  very much!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a chained multiplication approach with `reduce` to build a list of Series to ultimately `concat`:

```py
from functools import reduce
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age':[10, 20], 'height':[5, 6], 'weight':[100,150]
})

def chain_mul(cols):
    col_name = "*".join(cols)    
    series_dict = df[list(cols)].to_dict('series')
    col_prod = reduce(lambda x,y: x.mul(y), series_dict.values())
    return pd.Series(col_prod, name=col_name)    

# BUILD COLUMN COMBINATIONS (DUOS AND TRIOS)
sample_list = df.columns.to_list()
combns = (
    list(combinations(sample_list, 2)) +
    list(combinations(sample_list, 3))
)

# BUILD LIST OF COLUMN PRODUCTS
series_list = [chain_mul(cols) for cols in combns]

# HORIZONTAL JOIN
interactions_df = pd.concat(series_list, axis=1)

print(interactions_df)
#    age*height  age*weight  height*weight  age*height*weight
# 0          50        1000            500               5000
# 1         120        3000            900              18000
```

Comment: very nice and easy to understand code. However, I am getting a key error ("None of [Int64Index([50, 120], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]")  at the step where you generate the series_list. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Hmmm...I am on mobile so cannot test right now. Try removing the addition of lists in prior step to run one combination set.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work :( I will wait for your revision, appreciate your help!

Comment: I edited my answer. Looks like I overlooked that `reduce` requires raw values, so defined method passes in series rather than colnames.